# Unable to access user roles

Tags: php, error

We have updated an older site to a new version of Magento and given it a new look. It is live and everything is working except I can't change any user roles. When I go into System->Permissions->Roles->Add role (or click on an existing role) I get a blank screen. If I turn php errors on in index.php file I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminfee_Helper_Data' not found in /home/sites/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

And in the system log it shows this error:

```
Warning: include(Mage/Adminfee/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/sites/gwebsite/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

(shot in the dark) you have an extension called `adminfee` that has a section in the `adminhtml.xml` like this:

```
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <something_here translate="title" module="adminfee">
            <title>Some label here</title>
            <children>
    .....
```

but in the `config.xml` of the extension the helper alias is not defined.
you need to add this in `config.xml` of the extension inside the `<global>` tag.

```
<helpers>
    <adminfee>
        <class>[Namespace]_Adminfee_Helper</class>
    </adminfee>
</helpers>
```

replace `[Namespace]` with the real namespace of the module.

Comment: Good shot in the dark, but sadly I checked the config.xml and it's already in there :( the module is kgn_adminfee

Comment: now we are getting somewhere.  and what't the tag name under `<helpers>`? `adminfee` or `kng_adminfee`?

Comment: <adminfee>
     <class>Kgn_Adminfee_Helper</class>
</adminfee>

Comment: Strange. It should work. Is the extension enabled?

Comment: Yes it's enabled, I've just tried disabling literally every possible 3rd party plugin on the site and it still does it. It might be something missing in Magento core code, running 1.8.1.0 by the way.

Comment: strange indeed. It should work. did you clear the cache?

Comment: Indeed, strange. Copied over the core mage code with a new install core mage code and it didn't fix anything...so I'm lost